# xamarin.ios doesn't compile with vs2013

Tags: ios, xamarin, visual-studio-2013

I've just installed the brand new release of Visual studio 2013 and xamarin (ios + android).

But as soon as I try to debug a hello world application, nothing happens (the pairs works as a charm), the only informations given by VS are the following:

DEBUG log:

```
Getting device...
Starting debug on:iPhone 6.1
Remote build finished...
Debugging session ended.
Debugging session ended.
'Empty1.vshost.exe' (CLR v2.0.50727: Empty1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Empty1.vshost.exe' (CLR v2.0.50727: Empty1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Empty1.vshost.exe' (CLR v2.0.50727: Empty1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Empty1.vshost.exe' (CLR v2.0.50727: Empty1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Empty1.vshost.exe' (CLR v2.0.50727: Empty1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Empty1.vshost.exe' (CLR v2.0.50727: Empty1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Empty1.vshost.exe' (CLR v2.0.50727: Empty1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Empty1.vshost.exe' (CLR v2.0.50727: Empty1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\mscorlib.resources\2.0.0.0_fr_b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.resources.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'Empty1.vshost.exe' (CLR v2.0.50727: Empty1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Development\Workspace\Testing\Empty1\Empty1\bin\iPhoneSimulator\Debug\Empty1.vshost.exe'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The thread 0x2e60 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x5f5c has exited with code 259 (0x103).
'Empty1.vshost.exe' (CLR v2.0.50727: Empty1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Development\Workspace\Testing\Empty1\Empty1\bin\iPhoneSimulator\Debug\Empty1.exe'. Symbols loaded.
The program '[27752] Empty1.vshost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Mac server log:

```
[20-nov.-2013 20:21:17] Handling with command: [Info: CommmandUrl=Info] (31)
[20-nov.-2013 20:21:17] Attempting to acquire command execution lock, timeout set to 00:10:00
[20-nov.-2013 20:21:17] mtouch 7.0.4.209 (23a0827)

[20-nov.-2013 20:21:17] Command [Info: CommmandUrl=Info] finished (31)
```

someone have an idea ? I don't even know where to search for more error logs :/

Comment: I have the same problem. I can debug on iOS Emulator from Visual Studio 2013, and I can debug from MAC via Xamarin Studio on real device (iPad in my case), but I cannot debug on real device from Visual Studio 2013. BTW it doesn't work in VS 2012 either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. I installed Xamarin Studio 4.2.3 (alpha version) on Mac. Re-added my developer account from Xamarin Studio on Mac (make sure that your provisioning profiles are loaded correctly). After that I was able to run iOS app from Visual Studio 2013 on a real device.

Please check my response on Xamarin Forum too -

http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/11419/xamarin-ios-app-failing-to-run-on-device-from-visual-studio